# Jenkins Pipelines quiet period on downstream builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Background**

I have 3 builds in Jenkins all using a Jenkinsfile:

1. `client`
2. `ws`
3. `service`

The `client` is an NPM/NodeJS build which Docker image running HTTPD with a front end client "installed" and the `ws` is a back end Java web service (again in a Docker container). Both are Multiflow pipelines that are triggered by SCM commits.

The `service` build will be a build that creates a service template that allows the Docker images to be deployed together.

The problem I have is not with the builds themselves but with thier relationship with one another

Developers will commit and the multibranch pipelines will happily build away in the background, however when a merge is made to master (and the corresponding build is successful) the `ws` or `client` builds should start a `service` pipeline.

**The Problem**

The `service` pipeline should wait for a set period of time (5 mins?) before building. This will allow developers to merge to master across both applications and give the CI a chance to build both applications before attempting to build the `service`.

The reason for this is that there are stories that will involve updating both the `ws` and `client` that require both for the story to be tested properly (and pass!). Having the `service` pipeline wait will allow a developer to merge one master at a time without the build trying to build "prematurely" and gives Jenkins a chance for both builds to complete.

To add complexity, the version of the `ws` and `client` should be passed to the service build.

**What I've Tried**

Currently the `service` build is a parametrized build that prompts for the version numbers of the `ws` and `client`. When the `client` or `ws` builds it triggers the `service` with a quietPeriod:

```
    build job: 'service', parameters: [
    string(name: 'client', value: '1.0.0')], 
    quietPeriod: 60
```

(where 1.0.0 will be replaced with the Jenkins build number)

However this implementation causes the `client`/`ws` jobs to wait for 60 seconds before triggering the `service` build. What I want is for the `service` build to wait for 60 seconds before starting the build.

Comment: Is "_this implementation causes the `client`/`ws` jobs to wait for 60 seconds before triggering the `service` build._" really correct? According to the inline help of _Quiet period_: "_queued builds wait for the specified seconds before the actual build starts_" (or the like. I translated it from German text). So the sequence described there is: _U triggers_ → _D waits_ → _D builds_, not _U waits_ → _U triggers_ → _D builds_. Is this really different with [Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)?

Comment: Having played about with it a bit more this morning, what actually happens is the `ws`/`client` builds actually keep hold of an executor for the 60 seconds defined in the listening period while the `service` is listening.

Comment: It's different here: U runs and waits, D is "_(pending—In the quiet period. Expires in xx sec)_". No executor is used during this quiet/pending period. Maybe dependent on what is done before building D in U.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the confusion is that you wanted the `ws` and `client` builds to trigger the `service` build but not wait for the `service` build to begin executing.  To do this you can just add:

```
wait: false
```

To you build step.  From the docs here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/